# Is it possible to read a web page file online and host it with Arduino?

Tags: html, arduino, ethernet

I'm sorry if my title seems vague and uninformed, because that's the extent of my understanding right now.

I'm thinking of hosting a web server (with form methods, inputs, etc.) using an Arudino and an Ethernet shield. Now from what I've read, I know the web page (HTM/HTML file) does not have to be hardcoded into the microcontroller, but can instead by stored locally from an SD card that is read by the arduino. I know that level of separation is possible. However, I'm going to be away from my server quite a bit, and I'd like to be able to work on the web files regularly without having to physically restart the Arduino, remove the SD card and update the files, etc. I was wondering, since there can be already a level of separation between the HTML file and the Arduino, is it possible to 1)store the file online, in a file hosting service (maybe dropbox or skydrive or the like) so that the file could be read, 2)have the arduino read the file and host it as a webpage?

To rephrase, I'm trying to have two copies of the web page html; one stored on the SD card in the arduino, and one I'll work on while away from the arduino. What I'm trying to do is send this updated web page source file to the arduino and have it overwrite and host the new,updated web site file. 
I hope I'm being clear. If there's some easier option that I'm missing, that'd be helpful too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the Ethernet shield for GET requests too, so possibly you could poll your web server every so often (use a HEAD method & check for a `304 Not modified` response, if not, grab the new page) and store it to your SD card.

In this way, the SD card could act as a cache for the Arduino, but it would still be able to grab new content when available from your remote server.

Comment: That sounds good, although I'm still a little unsure about the details. Basically, you're saying I should write some method using get into the arduino code to read the web file stored somewhere online, see if there are changes, and if there are, download the new web file to the sd card, overwriting the old one, and host the new one instead?

Comment: Yeah, exactly — you could get your webserver to keep track of if the file has changed or not to take some of the heavy-lifting away from the Arduino. Then get the Arduino to send a `HEAD` request. If the file hasn't changed, the server sends back `304`, if it has, it sends back `200`. In the Arduino, if you get a `304`, serve from the SD card. If you get a `200` send a `GET` request, serve the response & then write the response to the SD card for next time.

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't that just be reading changes from the interactive webpage (ie button pressed, etc.) and writing that updated page to file? I mean I intend to do that, but that wasn't exactly my question. I was wondering, if I left the html file in the arduino sd card, I'd still be able to update a copy of the html file and send it to the server, probably using some desktop client app? Unless you are answering my question; in that case, how does your method differ from one that reads changes to the actual hosted website?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by interactive webpage (maybe you could expand the question with more detail?), I just meant that you could take advantage of how the `304` status code is implemented to let your Arduino both host the file, but also check a server for updates, as per the HTTP spec: www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5

Comment: I meant a webpage with radio buttons and other form methods. But I understand your answer now; it suggests two servers, right? One that holds the file, and the other to actually host that file. I'm not exactly sure how I would handle implementing the server that holds the file, how it would be "held", and how exactly arduino would read it(depending on how it's stored) and download it, however. Do you have any documentation or solutions as to that?

Comment: You could probably get away with just dropbox or similar, depending on how they'd support caching. For example, from a quick look at Dropbox API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata), it seems that they can provide a hash for a particular version of a file/folder. If the hash you send matches what they have stored, they'd send you back a `304`. This was you mightn't need a second server, you can get the Arduino to talk directly to dropbox via the API.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at the dropbox API, it seems like it should work. Well thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how practical this is using the setup you described, but I know that the Raspberry Pi could be used as a server. For example: [raspberry pi webserver](http://raspberrywebserver.com/). From a financial perspective, I think the Pi would be cheaper because you don't need the additional shields. (Ethernet and SD reader are built in)